# Regex in R--Words which don't end in specific characters in a line

Tags: regex, r

I have written the following line of code for "How many NAMEs end with something other than a vowel (aeiou)?"

```
> v
 [1] "Javon 0502 adrknqgpnbvbbxhhflnr"    
 [2] "Ariel 2312 dmqgkgpqipthwqaqwmjz"    
 [3] "Gunnar 5355 wddpbwdkgslaodvsdxps"   
 [4] "Marcos 4354 eoajpprooplrnfjhngll"   
 [5] "Juliana 1245 zogwfbgcfckkfnrrcgob"  
 [6] "Rolando 0505 nshlkeomtgsmwfmyouma"  
 [7] "Brayan 2322 gsqwwufgacspultfyogu"   
 [8] "Nola 0011 xvhvqppxzcjiyxghhzhy"     
 [9] "Gabriela 4501 dscxbkujflwowgohuzdk" 
[10] "Nikolai 0053 wjfftdaxsvwbjptbktao"  
[11] "Haylee 2301 sruhaqrggjiesrautogk"   
[12] "Kaia 3354 vfmocbpuavocrsviwdyd"     
[13] "Adalyn 1313 pddhqfqkyfngcyuuuooe"   
[14] "Rashad 5004 dkmvrcblsizfoiwzkpfx"   
[15] "Ariana 5105 zlfyhmvjxuqkcxbksxkb"   
[16] "Alexander 3323 kcrpuwqzgdfrogbjzmvr"
[17] "Maurice 1114 gbhwwdafadlggwsezsqj"  
[18] "Austin 3324 ofxaqpvfdobdewcbwiwg"   
[19] "Lacey 1050 lwbgaudzxbiwrxtsohbt"    
[20] "Julissa 5511 jshwvizbllnoaqgerdby"  
[21] "Fernanda 3535 qgakhgddxramvconxdoj" 
[22] "Natasha 5053 ejxchrbcagkhavvzdpte"  
[23] "Adam 3252 ruilxibrihxpnsxyorkx"     
[24] "Felix 5020 laotmpdjbfwdyfcjfixh"  

grep(pattern="^[aeiou]$",x=v)
```

The problem is that it finds the words that don't end with a vowel rather than just the first word in the line. How can I use regex to specify that?

P.S.: Every line has the form "NAME SCORES WORD" we just care about NAMEs not ending in a vowel.

Comment: Please use something like `dput(v)` next time.  Will make it much easier for people to test.  See **[Reproducible Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want the `invert` argument in `grep`.  It will return anything that's **NOT** the result of `grep`.  So if you `grep` for the vowels and use the `invert` argument, you get the names that **do not** end in vowels.

NOTE:  I have `v` set up as a data frame, not a vector here.

```
  > sapply(v, function(x){
      gsub("\\s[0-9].*", "", grep("[aeiou]\\s", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
    })
      V1         
 [1,] "Javon"    
 [2,] "Ariel"    
 [3,] "Gunnar"   
 [4,] "Marcos"   
 [5,] "Brayan"   
 [6,] "Adalyn"   
 [7,] "Rashad"   
 [8,] "Alexander"
 [9,] "Austin"   
[10,] "Lacey"    
[11,] "Adam"     
[12,] "Felix"
```

Comment: can you please explain how you just got the NAME? Like how can I get WORD using regex? `v2=sapply(v, function(x){
    gsub("\\*.s[0-9]", "", grep("[aeiou]\\s", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
})` ?

Comment: Getting only the name:  
It's the space.  Each name has a space after it.  WORD ends at a letter, no space. `[aeiou]\\s` means, "Any vowel and then a space."  Then, the `gsub` wrapper says "starting at the first space, substitute everything after that with `""`.

Comment: Get only WORD with  `sapply(v, function(x){ gsub(".*[0-9]\\s", "", grep("[aeiou]\\s", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)) })`.  The `.*[0-9]\\s` in `gsub` says to sub everything up to the first character after the space after the last number... if that makes any sense.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `^` incorrectly: you need to be using it inside the `[]`s so that it excludes vowels in the final consecutive alphabetic character starting from the beginning of each line.

```
grep(pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[^aeiou] ",x=v)
```

Comment: It doesn't give the right answer. every line has the form "NAME SCORES WORD" we just care about NAMEs not ending in a vowel.

Comment: It seems to work for me:

`v <- c( "Javon 0502 adrknqgpnbvbbxhhflnr", "Ariel 2312 dmqgkgpqipthwqaqwmjz", "Nikolai 0053 wjfftdaxsvwbjptbktaz");  grep(pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[^aeiou] ",x=v)` and I see `1 2` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to  `grepl("[^aeiou]$", v)`

Consider the following example:

```
> v <- c("Javon 0502 adrknqgpnbvbbxhhflnr",
         "Ariel 2312 dmqgkgpqipthwqaqwmjz",
         "Gunnar 5355 wddpbwdkgslaodvsdxps",
         "Marcos 4354 eoajpprooplrnfjhngll",
         "Juliana 1245 zogwfbgcfckkfnrrcgob",  
         "Rolando 0505 nshlkeomtgsmwfmyouma",  
         "Brayan 2322 gsqwwufgacspultfyogu")  
> grepl("[^aeiou]$", v)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**EDIT (update)**

To get what you need (updated question) try:

```
> ind <- grepl("[^aeiou]$", v)
> sapply(strsplit(v[ind]," "), "[", 1)
[1] "Javon"   "Ariel"   "Gunnar"  "Marcos"  "Juliana"
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer either. Please look at my updated question.